# Tree doesn't grow beyond size 3

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement the insertion subroutine in a binary search tree, each of whose nodes has a word(string) as key.
 I'm taking the words from STDIN and inserting them using the insert function. But whenever I take a inorder traversal, I find out that the tree is not growing beyond 3 nodes. What can be wrong? My code is attached here:

```
typedef struct treenode
{
  char word[20];             //word is the key for each node
  struct treenode *left;
  struct treenode *right;

} treenode;



treenode *insert (treenode *node, char *word)   
{   
  if(node==NULL)                       //if a null node is reached,make a temp node and append it
  {
    treenode *temp;
    temp = (treenode *) malloc(sizeof(treenode));
    strcpy (temp ->word,word);
    temp-> left = NULL;
    temp-> right = NULL;
    return temp;
   }


    if ((strcmp(word, node ->word)>0))  //if the key is greater than node.word,go to right child
    {
        node-> right = insert(node-> right, word);
    }
    else if(strcmp(word,node->word)<=0)  //if key <node.word,go to left child
    {
        node-> left = insert(node-> left, word); 
    }

}

void printinorder(treenode *node)
{

   if(node == NULL) return;
   printinorder(node-> left);
   printf("%s ",node-> word);
   printinorder(node-> right);

}



int main()
{
    treenode *root = NULL;
    char string[20];
    scanf("%s",string);  //first input is taken once here and once again inside loop,but its OK
    root = insert(root, string+1);  //duplicate entries are also stored

    while(strcmp(string,".")!=0)   //input is terminated by a full stop
    {
        insert(root, string+1); 
        scanf("%s",string);
    }


    printinorder(root);           //finally printing the BST
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want a return somewhere toward the bottom of this thing. And [avoid casting malloc in C programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Try debugger and have a look at `*insert()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, return worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you are trying to combine the `create_node` and `insert` into a single function which and then use that single function as a one-size-fits-all solution for tree initialization and insertion. Here it was causing complications with the return type from `insert` (as noted in the comments) and likely caused you to miss a needed recursion in `insert`. (**note** the addition of and an `else` in `insert` under both the `tree->right` and `tree->left` code)

You are better served splitting the `create_node` and `insert` routines into separate functions. This allows `create_node` to be defined as type `treenode` and `insert` to be defined as type `void`. This simplifies the code for each and makes following the logic easier and more readable. Doing so, your code then becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct treenode
{
char word[20];             //word is the key for each node
struct treenode *left;
struct treenode *right;

} treenode;

treenode* create_node (char *word)
{
    treenode* tmp = malloc (sizeof (struct treenode));
    if (tmp) {
        strcpy (tmp ->word,word);
        tmp->left = NULL;
        tmp->right = NULL;
    } else {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory exhausted\n", __func__);
    }
    return tmp;
}

void insert (treenode *tree, char *word)
{

    if (strcmp (word, tree->word) > 0)
    {
        if (tree->right == NULL) {
            tree->right = create_node (word);
            insert (tree->right, word);
        } else {
            insert (tree->right, word);
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp (word, tree->word) < 0)
    {
        if (tree->left == NULL) {
            tree->left = create_node (word);
            insert (tree->left, word);
        } else {
            insert (tree->left, word);
        }
    }
}

void printinorder(treenode *node)
{
    if(node == NULL) return;
    printinorder(node-> left);
    printf("%s ",node-> word);
    printinorder(node-> right);
}

int main()
{
    treenode *root = NULL;
    char string[20];
    scanf ("%s",string);  //first input is taken once here and once again inside loop,but its OK
    root = create_node (string);  //duplicate entries are also stored

    while (strcmp (string,".")!=0)   //input is terminated by a full stop
    {
        insert (root, string); 
        scanf ("%s",string);
    }

    printinorder(root);           //finally printing the BST

    return 0;
}
```

**build/run:**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bst bst.c
$ ./bst
my_dog
has
fleas
my_cat
likes
snakes
.
fleas has likes my_cat my_dog snakes
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments - **do not cast malloc**. It is unnecessary and increases the likelihood of error.